# Get process sessionid by command line from Blue Prism

Tags: powershell, cmd, blueprism, rpa

It is possible to get from Blue Prism, by command line, all sessionid of processes triggered NOT from the scheduler (and not triggered from the command line)?

There are commands to obtain the process sessionid when a process run from command line like

```
.\AutomateC.exe /run <processname>
```

or from the scheduler

```
.\AutomateC.exe /viewschedreport {<name> | <no-of-days> <date>} [/schedule <name>|...] [/format {csv|txt}]`
```

, but I need to get all sessionid, for example, sessionid of process I run from Session Manager. I need it to get status of the process by commend line:

```
.\AutomateC.exe /status <sessionid>
```

Answer (score 3):

The most reliable way to get this information would be to query the Blue Prism database directly.

You haven't specified the Blue Prism version you're working on, but the following is for a v6 implementation:

```
SELECT sessionid
FROM dbo.BPASession a
WHERE a.starteruserid <> (SELECT userid FROM dbo.BPAUser WHERE systemusername = 'Scheduler')
```

Comment: BP v6.3.2, thanks for response, I will test it soon.